# Can I prove back the inequality generated from two inequalities in the same form?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

$g(x)=\frac{L}{2}\|x\|_2^2-f(x)$, is a convex function. Therefore by first-order condition, there is

\begin{align*}
g(y) \geq g(x) + (Lx-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x) \,\,\,\,(1)\\
g(x) \geq g(y) + (Ly-\nabla f(y))^T(x-y) \,\,\,\,(2)
\end{align*}

By adding these two inequalities, I got,

$(Lx-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x)+ (Ly-\nabla f(y))^T(x-y) \leq 0 \, (3)$

My question is, it is always easy to construct two inequalities in the same form and by adding them together, we can get interesting structures. However, is there anyway that I can prove back? That is, given (3), can I derive (1) or (2)?

Comment: You seem to be asking whether $F(x) + G(x) \leq 0$ implies $F(x)\leq 0$ and $G(x)\leq 0$. Can you think of $F, G$ that disprove this assertion?

Comment: @user37208 I added the condition of convexity on $g(x)$. I want to assume $\exists x, y$ such that $g(y) < g(x) + (Lx-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x)$, there must be  $g(x) < g(y) + (Ly-\nabla f(y))^T(x-y)$ (I haven't proved yet, could it be?), by adding new inequalities together, we will have $(Lx-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x)+ (Ly-\nabla f(y))^T(x-y) > 0$, which contradicts to the previous assumption.